# multiple domains for API and Web App in ASP.Net 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have ASP.Net 5 Web App project.
I want to run my project, the API must be run on other domain e.g., `http://localhost:5000/api/` and the web app run on other domain e.g., on `http://localhost:60856/`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your solution structure? I believe you need two separate projects/ solutions, so that you have 2 different sets of binaries, one for each "website" that you need.

Comment: If you have 2 project in one solution, and you wanna start them at the same time, you can refer to [this tutorial](http://dotnet-concept.com/Tips/2019/12/5799873/Running-two-project-at-a-time-in-Visual-Studio-2019).